# WebFont shows uppercase or lowercase in different browser

Tags: css, webfonts

All, I found for the same font css of an element , The font shows uppercase in some browser, but lowercase in others. I inspect the element in the firebug . But didn't found any css attributes make it .I don't know which css attribute I should check. Does it have something with the Browser setting ? thanks.

**Edit**
I use the below way to implement the web fonts in the page. please review it .thanks.

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'MyWebFontNormal';
    src: url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Normal-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'MyWebFontBold';
    src: url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
               url('../webfonts/Novecentowide-Bold-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Wich browser (infact wich font used from font-fac) .Do you have same issue with another font, if not , then it might be a mistake to names given to files.

Comment: I see, I just doesn't have enough experience with using font face, I got you mean ,I will do some test for it .thanks.

Comment: @GCyrillus I just found the cause. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, I just found the main reason cause the incompatibility between browsers is because different browser only depend on the different font file. here is the detail of it . please review [it](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/). Another thing we should care about when use this css3 feature is the Mime Type of the Font file. Just make sure the server you used for example IIS is added the right Mime Type for the font file. Otherwise the browser can not recognize the type of the resource. Or sometimes will throw the 404 error although the resource is indeed there. thanks.